# On Quantum Harmonic Oscillator in Canonical Ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

I'm a bit confused with some results from the interpretation of the QHO in a canonical ensemble.

The partition function is given by the expression
$$Z = \sum_{s} e^{-\beta E_s},$$
where $s$ represents each microstate. My first question is: if a system consists on several QHO (let's suppose 2 for simplicity), this expression gives the total partition function (using that $E$ is the total energy of the two oscillators), right?

Knowing that the spectrum of energies in the QHO is given by
$$E_n = \hbar \omega \left( n + \dfrac{1}{2} \right),$$
if we want to calculate $Z$ for two oscillators, the partition function will be given by a double sum, one in $n_1$ and one in $n_2$, right (considering we have 2 oscillators; this could be generalised for $k$ oscillators, then we will have $k$ sums depending on $n_k$)?

Lastly, can we calculate $Z$ by calculating the partition function for 1 oscillator and then raising it to the number of oscillators? I've been told that I can do this when the particles are distinguishable and non-interacting, but when evaluating it for 2 oscillators I don't get the same result as evaluating the partition function in general.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703139/derivation-of-partition-function-for-n-identical-quantum-harmonic-oscillators) might be of interest.

Comment: You shouldn't use the scrip character $\mathcal{Z}$ for the regular partition function in the canonical ensemble.  The canonical partition function is just a regular $Z$, and $\mathcal{Z}$ is normally reserved for the grand partition fucntion of the grand canonical ensemble.

Comment: @Buzz I think OP might have meant to write "grand canonical." OP, did you mean grand canonical or canonical? The difference is that in the canonical ensemble $N$ is fixed, but in the grand canonical ensemble $\mu$ is fixed.

Comment: I am pretty sure that OP means the canonical ensemble, as they also ask about specific numbers (e.g. $2$ or $k$) or writes "raising it to the number of oscillators"...